# R Sub function to replace pattern that has spaces

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace a certain pattern of 4 characters in R, but am not sure the best way to approach it.  For example, if I have a string of:

J J DOE

I want the result to be "J.J. DOE".

What is the best way to accomplish this?  Note that it will not always be "J J ", it could be any two letters.

Comment: If all you need is `gsub("(\\S)(\\s)", "\\1.\\2", "J J DOE")`, then you're good. If not, I suggest you provide several more examples, perhaps with one that requires no changes, and several that are different enough but need a little change.

Comment: To replace each space with dot space `gsub(" ", ". ", "J J DOE")`

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Just replacing the space does not work because I don't want to replace all spaces.  For example, if it is "PETER SMITH", I don't want to replace anything.  I'm only looking to put periods after initials.  Further, in the case of "J J DOE", not only do I need to replace the spaces with periods, but I also then need to add a space before "DOE" to make sure there is a space between the second period and the last name.